# Minesweeper in C# Console - Board Implementation

Tags: c#, game, console, minesweeper

I created a simple minesweeper game in c#, and wanted to know how to improve it. I didn't really understand how to make it so everything besides the zero opens up.

How would I make my class Board better?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Minesweeper_trial
{
    class Board
    {
        public int[,] BoardPeices = new int[5, 5];
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void AddMine(Mine mine1)
        {
            BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY] = 9;
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void PrintBoard()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write(BoardPeices[x,y]);
                }
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void SetBoard()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                {
                    BoardPeices[x, y] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void NumberBesideMine(Mine mine1)
        {
            if (mine1.PositionX == 4 && mine1.PositionY == 4)
            {
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
            }
            else if (mine1.PositionX == 0 && mine1.PositionY == 0)
            {
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
            }
            else if (mine1.PositionX == 0 && mine1.PositionY == 4)
            {
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
            }
            else if (mine1.PositionX == 4 && mine1.PositionY == 0)
            {
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
            }
            else  if (mine1.PositionY == 4)
            {
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
            }
            else if (mine1.PositionX == 4)
            {
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
            }
            else if (mine1.PositionY == 0)
            {
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
            }
            else if (mine1.PositionX == 0)
            {
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
            }
            else
            {
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX + 1, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY + 1]++;
                BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX - 1, mine1.PositionY - 1]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to full code](https://github.com/ArtificialDog/MineSweeper)

Comment: Ok, i will edit it

Comment: Please add the full code, and not via a URL which can deprecate.

Comment: `BoardPeices` is that supposed to be `BoardPieces`? At least you've been consistent, but I'm not familiar with that spelling.

Comment: Sorry, I suck at english.

Comment: `wanted to know how to improve [a simple minesweeper game/board]` define *good*/*better*, and let in those you ask for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I understand you need to intersect your 5x5 board with a 3x3 square with a center in `mine1`.
It could be achieved via 2D loop (2 nested loops).

1. First (optional), if you use an old version of .NET that don't have the [`Math.Clamp`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.clamp) method, let's create a simple method to clamp a value `x` into the range `[min, max]`.

   ```
   private static T Clamp<T>(T x, T min, T max)
       where T : IComparable<T>
   {
       return x.CompareTo(min) < 0 ? min : x.CompareTo(max) > 0 ? max : x;
   }
   ```
2. Next, let's find a boundaries.

   ```
   int maxX = BoardPeices.GetLength(0) - 1; // Should be 4
   int maxY = BoardPeices.GetLength(1) - 1; // Should be 4

   int left = Clamp(mine1.PositionX - 1, 0, maxX);
   int right = Clamp(mine1.PositionX + 1, 0, maxX);
   int top = Clamp(mine1.PositionY - 1, 0, maxY);
   int bottom = Clamp(mine1.PositionY - 1, 0, maxY);
   ```
3. Finally, let's iterate.

   ```
   for (j = top; <= bottom; ++j)
   {
       for (i = left; <= right; ++i)
       {
           ++BoardPeices[i, j];
       }
   }
   --BoardPeices[mine1.PositionX, mine1.PositionY]; // undo the mine1 cell increment
   ```

Thus, items 2 and 3 together replace your `NumberBesideMine` method.

Comment: Why not `Math.Clamp`?

Comment: @aepot Indeed. It appeared in .NET Standard already. I missed that.